# Different DI implementation in Autofac based on Environment

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm trying to set different DI implementation for my interface `IBlobService` based on Environment.
For Dev I wanna use `LocalFileStorageRepository` and for Production will be `AzureStorageRepository` with constructor that requires `BlobServiceClient`.

```
builder.Register(c =>
{
    var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("environment_name");
    if (environment == "DEV")
    {
        return new LocalFileStorageRepository();
    }
    else
    {
        return new AzureStorageRepository(c.Resolve<BlobServiceClient>());
    }
}).As<IBlobService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

It doesn't work since `The type arguments for method 'RegistrationExtensions.Register<T>(ContainerBuilder, Func<IComponentContext, T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Any idea how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For configuration values that do not change at runtime, instead *wrap* the `Register` calls in the `if`-`else` check. This:

- simplifies registration
- improves performance
- ensures the availability of the environment variable is checked at startup

In other words, rewrite your registration to the following:

```cs
var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("environment_name");
if (environment == "DEV")
{
    builder.RegisterType<LocalFileStorageRepository>().As<IBlobService>()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
}
else
{
    builder.RegisterType<AzureStorageRepository>().As<IBlobService>()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
}
```

or optionally

```cs
var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("environment_name");
var blogServiceType = environment == "DEV"
    ? typeof(LocalFileStorageRepository)
    : typeof(AzureStorageRepository);

builder.RegisterType(blogServiceType).As<IBlobService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

> Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

or consider having the delegate return a common type

For example

```
//...

builder.RegisterType<LocalFileStorageRepository>();
builder.RegisterType<AzureStorageRepository>();
builder.RegisterType<BlobServiceClient>(); //<-- May need further details
builder.Register(c => {
    var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("environment_name");
    return (IBlobService) (environment == "DEV" 
        ? c.Resolve<LocalFileStorageRepository>()
        : c.Resolve<AzureStorageRepository>());
    
}).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

//...
```

Note the cast in the return statement.

The registration of `BlobServiceClient` may need further refinement depending on the explicit dependencies of `AzureStorageRepository`

Comment: Thanks. Btw. wrong casting. Move to next line so it should be `(IBlobService)c.Resolve<LocalFileStorageRepository>()`

Comment: If they are both `IBlobService` then the cast is in the right place

Comment: Ohhh Ok i see the error now: `Feature 'target-typed conditional expression' is not available in C# 8.0. Please use language version 9.0 or greater` :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@Nkosi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5233410/nkosi) answer - if you are able to use standard `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable for specifying/determining environment there is one other option: use multiple `Startup` classes with name conventions described in the [docs](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0#startup-class-conventions):

> The app can define multiple `Startup` classes for different environments. The appropriate `Startup` class is selected at runtime. The class whose name suffix matches the current environment is prioritized. If a matching `Startup{EnvironmentName}` class isn't found, the Startup class is used.

So in your case you can define "base" `Startup` (and use it as default one) and combine it with [template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) looking something like this (example code, maybe even does not compile, just to give you an idea):

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        RegisterEnvironmentAutofacServices(builder);
        ...
    }
    
    protected virtual RegisterEnvironmentAutofacServices(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        // do default registrations here or throw depended on your preferences
        builder.Register(c => new AzureStorageRepository(c.Resolve<BlobServiceClient>()))
            .As<IBlobService>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}

public class StartupDEV : Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration): base(configuration)
    {
    }

    protected override RegisterEnvironmentAutofacServices(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        // do environment specific ones:

        builder.Register(c => new LocalFileStorageRepository())
            .As<IBlobService>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach. Separates concerns nicely.